# Showing countability without explicit bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(The questions are below the question heading)

I've seen this image posted:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/tDSX24E.jpg]

I actually agree with it - that is not to say that $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't countable.

---

**Reasoning**
The definition of bijection is a useful starting point, and it is easy to see that $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable. I shall denote this as $\mathbb{Z}\sim\mathbb{N}$ for simplicity.

I then take:
$$f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\text{ by }\ f:(a,b)\mapsto\left\{\begin{array}{lr}\frac{a}{b} & \text{if }b\ne 0\\ 1 & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

There are other choices (like $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N} say) but this matters not. This mapping is **surjective** but not injective.

From this **we know now: $|\mathbb{Q}|\le|\mathbb{N}|$**

> I got my set theory book out to check this, and it exhibits a similar map to mine and considers it proven that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, this is not enough as a function that maps numbers to even and odd has a finite range. It would prove that it is *at most countable* though? Can I use that?

**I am not sure how to go from here, I was looking for a theorem along the lines of:**

> If $A\subseteq B$ then $|A|\le |B|$

We would then know that $|\mathbb{Q}|\le|\mathbb{N}|$ and $|\mathbb{Q}|\ge|\mathbb{N}|$

### Questions

1. Can I do that with infinities? Are they ordered? Does $\le$ make sense?
2. I know that *exhibiting a bijection*$\implies$ countability. As this is a definition it can be taken as $\iff$ (if we have a countable set, there must be a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ - if there isn't it violates that it is countable). *Thus for the statement in the image to be true* we cannot have countability of $\mathbb{Q}$ ($^*$)

---

($^*$) - damn, that shortens the point of this post.

Comment: By the way! It also just occurred to me that a bijection could exist, it'd just mean poking a lot of holes in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that each quotient only came up once - this'd be a lot of work though! It also suggests that my definition, _exhibiting_ a bijection, is wrong. It is that there must be a bijection. I do feel quite silly now. (~2mins after post)

Comment: Well, $ZF$ proves that there is a bijection $\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb Q$ and the [Theorem of Schröder-Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schröder–Bernstein_theorem) is not only famous for its (many different) wrong name(s), but also very useful to prove this claim.

Comment: There are plenty of explicit bijections.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question is wrong. A bijection between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z$ can be explicitly specified.

You seem to agree that there is a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$. Now enumerate $\mathbb Q$ by considering pairs $(p,q)\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ with increasing values of $m=|p|+|q|$. For each value of $m$, there are finitely many pairs $(p,q)$. Order them, say, lexicographically. For each pair, associate the next element of $\mathbb N$ with $p/q\in\mathbb Q$ iff this number hasn't previously been associated with an element of $\mathbb N$.

This establishes a bijection between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb N$, and thus between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: This is inline with the comment and something I realised when typing the second question. Before I tick though, I am uncomfortable with putting a partial ordering on cardinals (but have been assured it's okay to do so) and would love to be able to complete my proof (I was missing a $A\subseteq B\implies|A|\le|B|$ theorem, or something else I could use)

Comment: @AlecTeal: I don't know what you mean by "a partial ordering of the cardinals". If you want to complete your proof, I'd suggest that you post a new question, without all the stuff about there not being a bijection between $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$, focusing on the proof you want to complete.